# How do I find a certain value and replace it in and push all the values in a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, replace, find

I have a very basic knowledge of Javascript. I am writing a plugin to search for some predefined colors and replace them with new colors. So far I am able to get an array containing colors, name and styles as an object inside the array.

Now I want to search for a certain color like - `eb40a2` and replace it with `ffffff` and push this new value to a new array.

```
var ref=[];
....

ref.push({ name: styleName, color: styleColor, parent: styleParent, styles: styleId });
```

which is giving me the following array:

```
0: {name: "pink_theme/dark/fill/active", color: "eb40a2", styles: "S:5bebabedaa118ab6d135df59d7ba8861c05992a0,5:1"}
1: {name: "green_theme/light/fill/product", color: "c85200", styles: "S:380f15d999c08d9d97725c9915f479e52c1a343c,244:13"}
2: {name: "green_theme/light/fill/active", color: "00880d", styles: "S:b2aecc5927c659d7fba7d021b092bc90618043a5,189:0"}
3: {name: "green_theme/light/fill/product", color: "0081a0", styles: "S:1f28c38bfa1b10ca61aeaf706ac2a71fa6425950,244:11"}
```

Comment: must it be a new array? why  not just update the color in the current position

Comment: Can you help me with updating it in the current position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the array and conditionally update the colors you want. Check the code snippet below:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'pink_theme/dark/fill/active',
    color: 'eb40a2',
    styles: 'S:5bebabedaa118ab6d135df59d7ba8861c05992a0,5:1',
  },
  {
    name: 'green_theme/light/fill/product',
    color: 'c85200',
    styles: 'S:380f15d999c08d9d97725c9915f479e52c1a343c,244:13',
  },
  {
    name: 'green_theme/light/fill/active',
    color: '00880d',
    styles: 'S:b2aecc5927c659d7fba7d021b092bc90618043a5,189:0',
  },
  {
    name: 'green_theme/light/fill/product',
    color: '0081a0',
    styles: 'S:1f28c38bfa1b10ca61aeaf706ac2a71fa6425950,244:11',
  },
];

const newArr = arr.map(el => el.color === "eb40a2" ? {...el, color: "ffffff"}: el)

console.log(newArr)
```